# Google Map V3 With Three Marker Arrays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Below is some javascript based on the Google Maps documentation.  It should display a marker at the LatLng coordinates indicated.  However, it is showing the map only without the marker.  Can someone point out what I've done wrong? I've been staring at this for a long time and can't figure it out.  Also, I need to modify this code to accept two arrays of marker coordinates.  Each array is to get a different marker icon: red.png, yellow.png and blue.png.  I plan to eventually get the coordinates for each marker group by calling a server-side webmethod (C#).  But for simplicity let's ignore that requirement for the moment and assume we have three static arrays.  Can someone show me what I need to do? I've seen a lot of similar questions on S.O. but none of the answers seem to work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&sensor=true">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);
        map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(
new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35)));
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Markers are created as:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.50, -98.35),       
    map: map
    //, ...
});
```